# Python: Function calling from results of another function for Chatbot

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am creating a chatbot with pymessenger and wit.at. I am taking value through one entity suppose greeting and there I am setting parameters for another function but it is not working when I am calling other function.

```
def get_message():
    sample_responses = ["Hey Welcome May I know your Roll Number?", "Hi Welcome to  May I know your Roll Number"]
    return random.choice(sample_responses)

def cust(value):
    if value =="111":
        t1 = "Thor"
        val_off = "1"
    elif value =="222":
        t1 = "Steve"
        val_off = "2"
    elif value =="333":
        t1 = "Tony"
        val_off = "3"
    else:
        t1= ""
        val_off =""

def get_offer(val_off):
    if val_off == "1":
        offer_test = ("1. Thor"+"\n"+"2. Thor: Ragnarok+"\n"+"3. Avenger Series")
    elif val_off == "2":
        offer_test = ("1. First Avenger"+"\n"+"2. Winter Soldier"+"\n"+"3. Civil War")
    elif val_off =="3":
        offer_test = ("1. Iron Man 1"+"\n"+"2. Iron Man 2"+"\n"+"3. Civil War")
    return offer_test


app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    data = request.get_json()
    log(data)
    if data['object'] == 'page':
        for entry in data['entry']:
            for messaging_event in entry['messaging']:

                sender_id = messaging_event['sender']['id']
                recipient_id = messaging_event['recipient']['id']

                if messaging_event.get('message'):
                    if 'text' in messaging_event['message']:
                        messaging_text = messaging_event['message']['text']
                    else:
                        messaging_text = 'no text'

                    response = None

                    entity, value = wit_response(messaging_text)


                    if entity == 'cust_greet':
                        response = get_message()
                    elif entity == 'cust_id':
                        test = cust(str(value))
                        val_off = test[1]
                        offer_response = get_offer(str(val_off))
                        esponse = "Hey "+test[0] +". "+"\n"+"How Can I help you? Are you interested in"+"\n"+"1.Bio"+"\n"+"2. Movie list"
                    elif entity == 'cust_movie':
                        response = offer_response

                    bot.send_text_message(sender_id, response)
```

When provide roll number : eg.  111 function `cust()` will be called it will tell  the name as Thor and set `val_off = 1` and call the function `call_offer`. But when  I select option  "2. Movie list" I am getting error:

> "    response = offer_response
>   UnboundLocalError: local variable 'offer_response' referenced before assignment"

Comment: because `offer_response` is not assigned anywhere in your code

Comment: @RahulAgarwal: Thanks for quick response. I have already assigned it. see the snippet reference here:     elif entity == 'cust_id':
                    test = cust(str(value))
                    val_off = test[1]
                    offer_response = get_offer(str(val_off))

Comment: but you have assigned it in a `elif` block and the condition you are accessing is when the code doesn't go there. It has to be assigned globally to some value and can be changed when it enters a particular `if` block

Comment: I tried to change my code by adding this in first function but still getting same error: `def cust(value):
    if value =="111":
        t1 = "Thor"
        val_off = "1"
  offer_response = get_offer(str(val_off))
    elif value =="222":
        t1 = "Steve"
        val_off = "2"
  offer_response = get_offer(str(val_off))
    elif value =="333":
        t1 = "Tony"
        val_off = "3"
  offer_response = get_offer(str(val_off))
 else:
  t1= ""
  val_off =""
  return (t1,val_off,offer_response)`  I am new to python, can you tell where should I put the offer_response.

Comment: You have to add it where the `offer_response` gets assigned to some value even it is blank. So it gets assigned as soon as the code starts!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample function:

```
def cust(value):
offer_response ="" ## if it is a string
offer_response = 0 ## if it is a number
    if value =="111":
        t1 = "Thor"
        val_off = "1"
        offer_response = get_offer(str(val_off))
```

Try this:

```
elif entity == 'cust_movie':
    response = "Please let me know the type of movie by pressing only the digit"+"\n"+"1.Thor Series"+"\n"+"2. Avenger Series" +"\n"+"3.. Iron Man Series"
elif entity in( '1' , '2' ,'3'):
    response = get_offer(entity)
```

So, As you type "cust_movie" the bot will ask you to press the type of movie you want to see. It will store the value 1,2,3

As per user entry of 1,2 or 3 the bot will check for another elif loop and go to get_offer function  and the subsequent movie list will be displayed

Comment: I tried the same but when I say option 2 movie list: `elif entity == 'cust_offer': response = offer_response it will still giving same issue.

Comment: its says `  response = offer_response
NameError: name 'offer_response' is not defined` because now code is not going in cust() function.

Comment: Tell me what is your expected output and i will edit the code that way!!

Comment: Correct.. Thats y i was saying assign offer response where the code goes always.. So it always have a value

Comment: I will explain the example: if i say roll number is 111 then chatbot will take value =111 and run the cust() and ask me if i want bio or movie list. If i say movie list  then value variable is now = movie list. So now it should call get_offer() and give me 1. Thor. 2. Thor: Ragnarok 3. Avenger series. .... Thanks for your efforts and help Rahul

Comment: Check the updated answer, I have to tweak your logic as their is no way in present condition the bot will go to get_offer function when you enter movie list on bot screen

Comment: I have tried hardcode option and not calling movie list option separately. Thank you so much for all your help. Happy New year.